# How to run "dotnet xunit PathToLibrary.dll" from command line (in Continous Integration)

Tags: .net-core, xunit, xunit.net

I am able to "dotnet xunit" when I am in folder where the project is.

How can I do it from command line where I want to pass already compiled dll as a parameter.

```
dotnet xunit PathToLibrary.dll
```

I get an error:

```
No executable found matching command "dotnet-xunit"
```

I have copied "xunit.execution.desktop.dll" (get from nuget xunit.core.2.3.0) into current folder, but that does not help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

dotnet-xunit is a [per-project CLI tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/extensibility)

> Consuming these tools requires you to add a `<DotNetCliToolReference>` element to your project file for each tool you want to use. Inside the `<DotNetCliToolReference>` element, you reference the package in which the tool resides and specify the version you need. After running dotnet restore, the tool and its dependencies are restored.

So check that your .csproj contains

```
<ItemGroup>
   <DotNetCliToolReference Include="dotnet-xunit" Version="2.3.0" />
</ItemGroup>
```

then do

```
dotnet restore
```

Answer (score 5):

This answer isn't a direct answer to OP, but necessary for users of `dotnet xunit`

`dotnet xunit` is removed starting from xunit 2.4 [Ref: Release Notes 2.4](https://xunit.github.io/releases/2.4)

Excerpt from the Release Notes:

> Unfortunately, this release also removes the dotnet xunit runner, as the stability of the runner was never perfect, and it suffered from many assembly-loading related issues. Users from .NET Core can continue to use VSTest (either inside Visual Studio, or via dotnet test).

So, for xunit framework test use the [command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-test?tabs=netcore21)

```
   dotnet test
```